# OWIN Self-hosted Security Token Service (STS)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, claims-based-identity, adfs

I'm looking for suggestions regarding methods of hosting a 'custom STS' within a self-hosted OWIN pipeline.

It seems that the current documentation on custom claims providers has changed very little in the few years since I created a custom-STS with WIF 3.5, and I'd like to bring the implementation up-to-date for use with ADFS 3.1 (Windows Server 2012 R2).

I'm aware that the `SecurityTokenService` has moved to the `System.IdentityModel` namespace in 4.5, and ideally I'd like to encapsulate an STS within an OWIN-self hosted WebAPI, but I would be happy to use something like Nancy instead if necessary (since MVC does not appear to run in OWIN owing to it's reliance on `System.Web`), but I am struggling to find a way to utilise my implementation of `SecurityTokenService` from my WebAPI's `DelegatingHandler` since the wrapper functions in `System.IdentityModel.Service.FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations` also appear to be reliant on `System.web`, and hence IIS.

I plan on presenting the required input form elements to the user by manually crafting the response stream and parsing the POST - I realise this is a terrible idea compared to using ASP.Net or MVC, but at this stage this is really just a proof of concept for me, I'll be letting ADFS handle the cookies, since this will just be registered as a custom claims provider.

Should I drop the `SecurityTokenService` class in favour of a better token-generation implementation, or should I drop the wrapper class and manage requests to the STS manually using the `IOwinContext`'s `Request` and `Response` objects, but if so, how?

Many thanks

Comment: I managed to get a token by passing a RequestSecurityToken to the STS's Issue method, using a fake ClaimsPrincipal for the time being. The question now is what exactly to do with the token?!